# Angular recursive ng-include while keeping track of recursion depth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I have a situation that is pretty similar to this answer to the question here:

[AngularJS ng-include with nested hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203926/angularjs-ng-include-with-nested-hierarchy)

I have some data in the format

```
 $scope.data = {
text: "blah",
comments: 
[
  {
    text: ["blahL11", "blahL12", "blahL13"],
    comments: [
      { 
        text: ["blahL111", "blahL112", "blahL113"] 
      },
      { 
        text: ["blahR111", "blahR112", "blahR113"] 
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: ["blahR11", "blahR12", "blahR13"] 
  }
]
```

};

And I am display it with a recursive ng-include like this:

```
  <ul>
   <li>{{data.text}}</li>
   <li ng-repeat="item in data.comments" ng-include="'tree'"></li>
 </ul>

 <script type="text/ng-template" id="tree">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="text in item.text">{{text}}</li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in item.comments" ng-include="'tree'"></li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8swLos2V6QRz6ct6GDGb?p=info

However, I would like to somehow keep track of the depth of the recursion as well. So that instead of simply displaying:

```
-blah
    -blahL11
    -blahL12
    -blahL13
            -blahL111
```

It could display

```
-1. blah    
    -2. blahL11
    -2. blahL12
    -2. blahL13
        -3. blahL111
```

Without me modifying the data structure (as the depth is only really for display?). Can I insert a variable into the ng-include, is there some sort of recursive $index I can use?

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-tree, it has this built in and otherwise works allot like recursive ng-includes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `ng-init`.  This will assign a value to the new scope when it's created, which you can do by refering to a value in the old scope and incrementing it.

[plnkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/qCTP6mHdbo5mU1UWVHRx?p=preview)

```
<li ng-repeat="item in item.comments" ng-include="'tree'" ng-init="depth = depth + 1"></li>
```

Comment: That's awesome! I was trying to use onload, didn't think of ng-init. Thanks!